# URL param (route segment) containing the `/` character in Next.js app router

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13

My goal is to parse routes such as `object/abcd`, but also `object/ab/cd`, `object/a/b/c` and `object/a/b/c/d` with a single `page.tsx`. All of these should be parsed as `object/[anythingremaining]`. Given a Next.js 13 route of `object/[id]/page.tsx` it will however not match for example `object/abc/d` (giving a 404 error instead).

Is there a way to configure Next.js to match the `/` character in a URL segment?

I know that I could create 10 nested `page.tsx` (e.g. `object/[id1]/[id2]/[id3]/[id4]/[id5]/[id6]/page.tsx`) where each would export the root `page.tsx` and the root `page.tsx` would combine all the params together into a single param, but that seems absurdly messy.

Comment: `/` is the delimiter _between_ route segments. Maybe you need a different URL structure.

Comment: Have you tried catch-all segments? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments

Comment: @Danila Thank you, I am embarrassed to say I spend some serious time in the docs and somehow didn't see that  . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to restructure your URL patterns as this use case seem to conflict with how NextJS thinks about URLs. However, if you are determined to structure your URLs like this, you could probably use rewrites in your next.config.js like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: '/object/:id/:path*',
          destination: '/object/:id',
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

This will pass the :path parameter automatically in the query. You can [read more about rewrites here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites).